# Scala + Play Framework + Slick + Akka - DB Access from Akka Actor

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, slick

At the receival of a TCP specific message, i need to query my DB. For that, i created an Actor that is called DBActor and it's loaded in `Application.scala` file

```
    class Application @Inject() (system: ActorSystem) extends Controller {

      val tcpServer = system.actorOf(Props[TCPServer], "tcpserver")
      val dbActor = system.actorOf(Props[DBActor], "dbActor")
    }
```

Tcp server is the actor that received the message and need to push it on DB Actor with that

```
      val handler = context.actorSelection("/dbActor")
```

DB actor is so initialized in this way, according to Play Framework specifications

```
    object DBActor {
      def props() =
        Props(classOf[DBActor])
    }


    class DBActor @Inject() (protected val dbConfigProvider:
         DatabaseConfigProvider) extends Actor 
         with HasDatabaseConfigProvider[JdbcProfile] 
         with ActorLogging 
         with TableComponent {

      import akka.io.Tcp._
      import driver.api._

      val table = TableQuery[Table]

      def receive: Receive = {
        case GetConfig(id) => {
          sender ! Await.result(db.run(table.filter(_.id=== id).result.headOption), 
                Duration.Inf)
            .map { x => x.config }
        }
      }
    }
```

At the moment, actor is not constructed due to the error

```
    Error injecting constructor, java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
      no matching constructor found on class tcp.DBActor for arguments []
      at controllers.Application.<init>(Application.scala:17)
      at controllers.Application.class(Application.scala:17)
```

So i need a way to inject the db configuration in the DBactor for querying the database or an alternative. I evaluated before that to inject a DAO or transforming the DAO I needed into an actor, both failed.

Question at this point is, does it make any sense giving an actor the access to the db or, at least, a controller? If can't be done, what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you need is an injected actor. The full description can be found here in the play documentation (https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaAkka#Dependency-injecting-actors), but here's the gist of it:

You define the actor binding like so:

```
bindActor[DBActor]("db-actor")
```

And inject the actor in the controller like so:

```
class Application @Inject() (@Named("db-actor") dbActor: ActorRef) extends Controller {
```

On a different note, you should avoid `Await.result` whenever possible. In your scenario, this could probably easily be replaced with:

```
val senderRef = sender()
db.run(table.filter(_.id=== id).result.headOption)
  .map(res => senderRef ! res.config)
```

Note that the sender ref is stored before, because it is no longer valid inside the `map` (see scaladoc of the `sender()` method).

Comment: Ok, it did work, i've to register all actors of application in this way. Thanks