# Play Slick Global Lookup setup deprecated message

Tags: playframework, slick, playframework-2.5, slick-3.0, play-slick

As stated in [Play Slick documentation](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/PlaySlick#DatabaseConfig-via-Global-Lookup) a DatabaseConfig object can be obtained via Global Lookup:

```
val dbConfig = DatabaseConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile](Play.current)
```

However I get the following compilation warning stating that `current` is deprecated and that I should use DI instead:

> [warn] C:\myapp\app\test\Test.scala:28: method
>   current in object Play is deprecated: This is a static reference to
>   application, use DI instead

Am I forced to use DI instead of global lookup? With the deprecation warning the database connection works fine.

Comment: `Play.current` will be removed with play 2.6

Comment: How should I use global lookup?

Comment: I guess this goes into the same direction: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40804275/scala-play-framework-slick-akka-db-access-from-akka-actor/40804616#40804616

Comment: I'm not using akka actors. Am I forced to use injection?

Comment: You are forced to pass in a reference one way or the other. Dependency Injection is one way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either inject actually Play app (and pass it as parameter as you did) or better, inject `DatabaseConfigProvider` itself - in that way it won't need Application:

```
@Singleton
class DbAccessPlayConfig @Inject()(dbConfigProvider: DatabaseConfigProvider) {
  val dbConfig = dbConfigProvider.get[JdbcProfile]
}
```

Comment: Can I access dbConfig (the one you defined in the Singleton) from multiple threads? how should concurrency be managed in this case?

Comment: I guess what you do with `DbConfig` most of the times is basically get `db` out of it (which needs to be thread-safe anyway). `db` field is simply `val` inside so it should be safe.